# ActiveAdmin + CanCan + AASM event switcher with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan, aasm

```
As an admin I have a specific role
I want to see and switch event for object
Depends on my role
```

Inspired by [activeadmin_addons](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/) and its [Enum Integration](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/enum_integration.md#interactive-tag-column) I want to make similar functionality for AASM by letting diffent admin users change events depending on their abilities/roles for specific  events/statuses in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Taken from here, please see this link for additional files you need](https://gist.github.com/alexey/446c6c4ce2a5af0f4fb6851e6d6d514e)

**Prequestites:**

Gem: ActiveAdmin, 
Gem 'active_admin_role', both are installed and working AdminUser model with current_admin_user setup (or similar to your app).

Tested with Rails 5.1.3.

After you finish and deploy/run server you must "Reload" Permissions in admin and enable "event_update" for manager or other than "super_admin" roles.

**Smaller addons you'll need to do:**
(in addition to below attached files)

In your AdminUser model add:

```
include CanCan::Ability
include ActiveAdminRole::CanCan::Ability
```

In your table_for (is where you render columns of data):

```
column 'Our Status' do |auction|
  render 'admin/auctions/event_change', auction: auction
end
```

In initializers/active_admin.rb or whenever you want

```
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
  protected

  def current_ability
    # Match to your current admin user
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)
  end
end
```

**also make sure your config:**

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
config.cancan_ability_class = 'Ability'
```

Pardon me if I forgot something, let me know if you have any question or problem !